# Understanding the $1$-norm of $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I have a quick question about a proof I was reading. The proof is basically asking about the continuity of the translation operator in the $L^1$-norm. Here is a snippet of the proof[image]

I am not sure how their integral over $\mathbb{R}^d$ turned into just an integral over $E$ (first line to second). It seems to me that this is not too clear. Unless I am missing something very simple...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about what the support of $F - F_h$ is

Comment: @PhysMath: Thank you for your comment. But wouldn't the support of $F-F_h$ be $E \Delta (E+h)$?

Comment: The proof is wrong. Where did you find it?

Comment: Yeah I believe you're right, but i think you can upper bound by all of $E$ plus the set $E+h$ which is just $E$ shifted by $h$. (So actually i think there a small error in the proof but the same idea works).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I found a link while studying and this problem was interesting to me but I could not follow that line. Do you have any recommendations on how to prove this when $F \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: @PhysMath: Thank you, yes I agree that maybe not all hope is lost!